# Does DELETE CASCADE Option for Foreign Keys delete grandchildren?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, fluent-interface

pretty new to SQL cascading delete. I was wondering how cascade delete works when it comes the children. So say I have a table situation like:

> **ParentTable** ==Cascade==> **ChildTable** ==NoCascade==> **GrandChildTable**

Will the grandchild also be deleted? Do I need to specify in the childtable to turn off cascade delete? I am using Fluent API to set the cascade delete for the parent ParentTable to the ChildTable with WillCascadeOnDelete(true), should I set WillCascadeOnDelete(false) on the ChildTable, is this necessary? The reason I can not delete the GrandChildTable is because it is a domain table.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: On which database system?

Comment: @duffy356: do you know a serious database system which does behave this way?

Comment: you should probably use on delete set null. otherwise you will get an error.

Comment: MSFT SQL Server and Is there any way to limit that cascade to be one way. So if I delete the parent, it deletes the child but not vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will the grandchild also be deleted?

No, not if your database system is not completely buggy, or lets say incompletely implemented (and this has not much to do with entity framework). If that would be possible, you could easily destroy data integrity against the intentions of those foreign key constraints.

If you want grandchilds to be deleted when a child gets deleted, you need an additional DELETE CASCADE constraint on the FK relation from ChildTable to GrandChildTable. It does not matter if the DELETE operation on the child comes from an explicit DELETE for that child, or from a cascading delete for the parent.

Comment: Ok thats what I though, at least what would make sense to me. Thanks Doc Brown, see ya in the future

Comment: One thing to add here, if you want to delete the grand children, in addition to what Doc Brown said, you need to fetch the grand children collection from the children eagerly.